# pre-commit run --all-files An error has occurred: InvalidManifestError: while configure pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

steps:

1. I was installed -->

```
$ pre-commit install
pre-commit installed at .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

2.create .pre-commit-config.yaml file then add configuration. this is my pytest configuration

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest
    rev: 7.4.3 
    hooks:
      - id: pytest
```

while run the pre-commit run --all-files i got error on pytest section

error:

```
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest.
An error has occurred: InvalidManifestError: 
=====> /home/mutharasu/.cache/pre-commit/repofxmga3dy/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml is not a file
```

Check the log at /home/mutharasu/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log

i want run successfully on that pre-commit run --all-files command

Comment: Is the filename `.pre-commit-config.yaml` or is it `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml` ?

Answer (score 2):

pytest-dev/pytest does not provide a hook for use with `pre-commit` -- that is it does not contain a `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml` file with information.

I'm not sure where you found that yaml snippet from, but it is not valid (perhaps you made it up?)

and as both a pytest core dev and the creator of pre-commit it shouldn't -- running tests as part of your commit is going to be too slow and is going to frustrate your contributors.  plus pre-commit never installs the "repository under test" so you won't be able to have any of your dependencies available

Comment: here yaml is the root then also configured other techs also like black,pylint and bandit also but this pytest only not working. and also once developer compolete their task then try to commit that time pre-commit enter the action so pre-commit is  the root ( here based on our requirement we can change the test)

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying